# Optimization of C++ code - std::vector operations

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

[image]

I have this funcition (RotateSlownessTop) and it's called about 800 times computing the corresponding values. But the calculation is slow and is there a way I can make the computations faster.

The number of element in X/Y is 7202. (Fairly large set)

I did the performance analysis and the screenshot has been attached.

```
void RotateSlownessTop(vector <double> &XR1, vector <double> &YR1, float theta = 0.0)
{
Matrix2d a; 

a(0,0) = cos(theta);
a(0,1) = -sin(theta);
a(1, 0) = sin(theta);
a(1, 1) = cos(theta);

vector <double> XR2(7202), YR2(7202);

for (size_t i = 0; i < X.size(); ++i)
{
    XR2[i] = (a(0, 0)*X[i] + a(0, 1)*Y[i]);
    YR2[i] = (a(1, 0)*X[i] + a(1, 1)*Y[i]);
}
size_t i = 0;
size_t j = 0;

while (i < YR2.size())
{
    if (i > 0)
        if ((XR2[i]>0) && (XR2[i-1]<0))
            j = i;

    if (YR2[i] > (-1e-10) && YR2[i]<0.0)         
        YR2[i] = 0.0;

    if (YR2[i] < (1e-10) && YR2[i]>0.0)
        YR2[i] = -YR2[i];                     

    if ( YR2[i]<0.0)
    {
        YR2.erase(YR2.begin() + i);
        XR2.erase(XR2.begin() + i);
        --i; 
    }
    ++i;
}
size_t k = 0;
while (j < YR2.size())
{
    YR1[k] = (YR2[j]);
    XR1[k] = (XR2[j]);
    YR2.erase(YR2.begin() + j);
    XR2.erase(XR2.begin() + j);
    ++k;
}
size_t l = 0;
for (; k < XR1.size(); ++k)
{
    XR1[k] = XR2[l];
    YR1[k] = YR2[l];
    l++;
}
}
```

Edit1: I have updated the code by replacing all push_back() with operator[], since I read somewhere that this is much faster. 
However the whole program is still slow. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `vector::reserve` may help.

Comment: Are you running a debug build or a release (optimized build)?  If it's a debug build, your results are meaningless.  Please post the compiler optimization settings you used.  This is especially the case with Visual Studio, as debug builds puts in tons of iterator checking in the STL container classes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am running in release. The settings are:
Optimization: Maximize speed(/O2)
Inline Function Expansion: Default
Enable Intrinsic Functions: Yes(/Oi)
Favor Size or Speed: Neither
Omit Frame Pointers: No(/Oy-)
Enable Fiber-Safe Optimizations: No
Whole Program Optimization: Yes(/GL)

Comment: On a high-level, what are you trying to accomplish with the first and second `while` loops?  Whatever it is, it sure looks like an algorithm function would do the job rather than hand-coded loops.  In addition, every time you call `erase`, the vector has to move elements to cover up the hole that was created.  This in itself could be a bottleneck (and I wouldn't be surprised if it's `erase` that's causing the problems you're seeing, and not `reserve` or `[ ]`.

Answer (score 2):

If the size is large, you can improve the `push_back` by pre-allocating the space needed. Add this before the loop:

```
XR2.reserve(X.size());
YR2.reserve(X.size());
```

Comment: I have replaced push_back() with operator[], because I read somewhere it was faster. It's still slow.